# Varnish: Making each API keys objects cache separately

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I have Varnish 4 installation where I select a backend based on an API-key in the header of each request, such as (we are in vcl_recv):

```
if (req.url ~ "/content") {
    # Check for presence of X-Api-Key header
    if ((! req.http.X-Api-Key) || ((! req.http.X-Api-Key ~ "prod-") && (! req.http.X-Api-Key ~ "test-"))) {
        return(synth(403,"Access Denied - API key missing or invalid."));
    }
    if (req.http.X-Api-Key ~ "prod-") {
        set req.backend_hint = PROD.backend();
    }
    if (req.http.X-Api-Key ~ "test-") {
        set req.backend_hint = TEST.backend();
    }
}
```

However, objects fetched from the PROD backend can get delivered to requests to the TEST backend, if their TTL is not expired, and vice versa.

How do I make sure that content from each backend is isolated from the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is easy. Since you want the cache to vary by specific header, you should tell Varnish about it. So either make your backend send `Vary: X-Api-Key` (best route), or have Varnish `hash` on that header's value:

```cpp
sub vcl_hash {
    if (req.http.X-Api-Key) {
        hash_data(req.http.X-Api-Key);
    }
}
```